# Recover changes from aborted git commit

Tags: git, git-gui

I started Git Gui, clicked Ctrl+I to stage all the modified files, typed a text message and clicked Commit. An error message saying that an Excel file was locked appeared asking whether to try again or stop.

I think I clicked the stop button (not sure), Git Gui closed, I closed the Excel file, and now most of my files are gone.

There were about 6-7 staged files, and now 30-40 files are missing.

Not only do I miss the files modified in the last 2-3 days, I miss also many other files. I think I can recover the old files by checking out the last commit, but how do I restore the changes of the last 2-3 days?

Comment: "There were about 6-7 staged files, and now 30-40 files are missing." <-- just to be absolutely clear, you mean they are missing from the file system or missing from the staging area / index of git?

Comment: They are missing from the file system. After opening PyCharm I saw 5 editors showing the same file because their files were missing. git status shows ~30 red lines with `deleted: ...`. (I use Git Gui instead of PyCharm because I often use stage hunk or line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume there was a `git add ...` done at some point since you were trying to commit, so you should be able to recover these files since git does save added files (staged but uncommitted) as well as committed files.  Try running `git fsck --lost-found` and it will output the folder of where it found lost & found files.  Good luck.

Comment: This is the output of `$ git fsck --lost-found / 
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done. / 
Checking objects: 100% (1840/1840), done. / 
dangling blob 3400e6a9afd884989fb68162626782c5527aba81 / [...] / dangling blob e2fff20d160f6a6047ed95291c0a7a0ed653bb1e  
` It's 100+ lines

Comment: by "100+ lines" you mean 100+ files listed as dangling blobs? use `git cat-file -p <commit hash>` to view the files, then hopefully you can see the contents to verify that the blob is the file you need.  If excel files are unreadable files, you may need to pipe it to a file and open with excel...Just a guess here.

Comment: @stenci try one more thing.  Navigate to the hidden directory path: ".git/lost-found" . I believe these files are non-compressed and will be readable.  Do a grep for the file you're looking for.

Comment: I found my stuff, yay!! It had been committed correctly. Then since I clicked on the abort button (I guess) Git Gui tried to revert back to the same condition as before the commit and messed it up. The lost-found folder has 299 items all created today at 7:49, but using grep I only found old code, none of my recent changes were there. The only one test that was failing before the commit is failing now. I feel much better now.